# Problem with static field in asp.net web-site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET web-site. In one of my pages, I had a static field for the current logged in user's CompanyId.

```
private static Guid _CompanyId = Company.Get().CompanyId;
```

Company.Get() returns the information about the company of the currently logged in user, where the UserId is retrieved using:

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();
```

But when logging in as another user, in antoher company, *Company.Get().CompanyId* would return the Guid from the first company.

Have I missed the point of using static fields, or does this have another cause?
I fixed it, by replacing all the references to *_CompanyId* in my code-behind with the *Company.Get().CompanyId* for a quick fix, but this is not really a good solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

static variable value persist at the application level and hence across user wise. you should use session to store your information. static variable value is not change until you reassign the value, application restart, etc..

Answer (score 3):

You should use HttpContext.Current to store session level variables. static variables are visible to all sessions in your web application.

Comment: Use HttpContext.Current.Session to store per-user, per Session variables..  Agreed, static variables are visible to all users on the current server.

In a webfarm environment, storing variables in the HttpContext.Current.Items collection will not allow that data to travel with the user to another server in the farm.

Comment: static variables will not travel with the user, but sessions can be shared between servers in a webfarm using out of process session storage. Microsoft Velocity (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx) is shaping up to be an excellent distributed caching solution.

Comment: But is this solution safe? Do I need to encrypt the contents? The CompanyId must not be changeable whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

Removing `static` from your field definition should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for an explaination to why it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think so, making the field instant (non-static) doesn't solve the problem, because it won't be persisted even on the session level